# Confused on Calculating Resistance Distance Matrix

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, linear-algebra

I am trying to create a computer program to compute the equivalent resistance over any points on any rectangular set of resistors (all with a resistance of 1 ohm). It seems that the [resistance distance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_distance?) is exactly what I need. I understand how to compute the inverse and what a Laplacian matrix is, but what is the difference between $\Gamma_{ii}$, $\Gamma_{jj}$, and $\Gamma_{ij}$ in $\Omega_{ij} = \Gamma_{ii}$ + $\Gamma_{jj} - 2\Gamma_{ij}$?

Answer (score 1):

$\Gamma_{ii}$ is the $i$-th entry on the diagonal of $\Gamma = L^+ = (D-A)^+$, $\Gamma_{jj}$ is the $j$-th entry, and $\Gamma_{ij}$ is the entry located at row $i$, column $j$. Thus $\Omega_{ij}$ is a scalar, but you could assemble all such values into a matrix $\Omega$ that gives the resistances between all pairs of vertices.